# analyze the structure of a long sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> Thus, a highly-accurate automatic fall detection system is likely to
>   be a significant  part of the living environment for the elderly to
>   expedite and improve the medical care  provided while allowing people
>   to retain autonomy for longer.

The above is the long sentence.

(1) what's the meaning of 'expedite' here?

(2) 'and improve the medical care', what's it before 'and'? I mean which 
part is **and** to 'improve the medical care'

(3) what's the meaning of 'while' here?

Comment: Basic meaning: _The system is likely to be a part, in order to `e&i` the care, while allowing longer autonomy_. Inserting commas after _elderly_ and after _provided_ is necessary; leaving them out of the written version is the cause of the problem. "Expedite `X`" means 'make `X` happen faster'. The _and_ connects the two verbs `expedite & improve`, which both take _the medical care provided_ as direct object. _While_ here means 'and at the same time.'

Comment: The whole sentence needs a rewrite, since the first and second halves are at syntactic cross purposes, as if (what often happens) the writer began with one syntactic plan, switched to another, and never fully followed through with the change. From "to expedite and improve" forward we have a perfectly good statement of the purpose of the action (as @JohnLawler clarifies by inserting "in order" above); but the main clause preceding has no action at all.

Comment: I'd be at least as likely to use ***whilst*** as ***while*** there, but I think all three sub-questions are effectively General Reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

Thus, a highly-accurate automatic fall detection system is likely to be a significant part of the living environment for the elderly.  Such a system can expedite and improve the medical care and allow people to retain autonomy for a longer period.

Comment: -1 Sorry, I down voted this because it's NOT an analysis of the sentence which is what the author asked for. Had he asked for a rewrite I would have up voted.

Comment: @Frank ...........That is O.K. ............I felt the analysis could be avoided by the re-write.